# Heroku and adding SSH keys (trouble installing heroku gem

Tags: ruby, macos, command-line, ssh, heroku

I am new to programming and trying to understand this error. The error is really strange because I have already installed the heroku gem (using sudo and not using sudo). I am using OS X.

```
skline-mac:~ skline$ sudo heroku keys:add 
/Users/skline/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:861:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem heroku (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/skline/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:255:in `activate'
    from /Users/skline/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1204:in `gem'
    from /Users/skline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:18:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using rvm, so there's no need for sudo, either for `gem install heroku` or using the heroku gem. This should work without any use of sudo:

```
gem install heroku
heroku keys:add
```

If this does not work, try resetting the ownership on your .rvm directory to your own user account (because you used sudo at some point in the past):

```
sudo chown -R $USER:staff ~/.rvm
```

Comment: when i do this I now get the error: No ssh public key found in /Users/skline/.ssh/id_[rd]sa.pub.  You may want to specify the full path to the keyfile. However, I do in fact of SSH keys at that location...

Comment: Try: `sudo chown -R $USER:staff ~/.ssh`

Comment: Well from what you've told me, it should work. I'd recommend double checking everything in your `~/.ssh` directory, possibly regenerate your ssh keys (`ssh-keygen -t rsa`).

Comment: See I tried to add more keys, but unless I use sudo, it tells me that permission is denied

Comment: Sudo will not solve your problems, it will only get you into more trouble, unless you use it to fix your permission problems. If it says permission denied, then you have a permission problem with your `.ssh` folder. I tried to fix that with my command above.